# Why adding babel-loader in webpack conf file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am new to webpack and have seen some examples as following:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      // ....
```

Why is this necessary since webpack auto transpiles es6 to es5?

---

Edit:
Ok, it DOES NOT transpile automatically unless instructed to do so.

Comment: Webpack does not auto-transpile ES6 to ES5, what resource led you to that conclusion? It is simply a build tool. It does nothing but execute the plugins & loaders you tell it to.

Comment: But the es6 code I wrote get transpiled to es5 even without this "babel" rule...

Comment: What ES6 code are you using that is transpiled to ES5? Can you share some of the code, what it transpiled to, what webpack related packages exist in your `package.json`, and the plugins you're using in your `webpack.config.js`? I'm sure there is something somewhere that is causing the transpilation.

Comment: Really thank you for replying. You can check my repo [here](https://github.com/thissentenceiswrong/CurrencyConverter/tree/nobabel). the entry file is [`src/js/main.js`](https://github.com/thissentenceiswrong/CurrencyConverter/blob/nobabel/src/js/main.js), and its written in es6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this necessary since webpack auto transpiles es6 to es5?

Webpack does not auto-transpile ES6 to ES5. It is simply a build tool. It does nothing but execute the plugins & loaders you tell it to.

> But the es6 code I wrote get transpiled to es5 even without this "babel" rule

I don't see it transpiling ES6 to ES5.

The first example I looked for in your code was the conversion of `let` to `var` in the bundled code since this is probably the most commonly used ES6 feature.

With babel-loader, `let` gets converted to `var` (and some other fancy maneuvering). Without, it remains `let`.

To explore this, I commented out UglifyJS so the bundle was readable and `ctrl+f`ed the file. You should be able to see this same behavior.

If you're expecting `import` to be converted to `require`, this won't happen as webpack just reads the file and loads it into the bundle. So, no `require` & no `import` appear in the bundle. This isn't transpilation, though. It's just a function of how webpack's bundling process works (searching for & injecting dependencies into the bundle).

## Bonus points:

I would recommend adding your `dist` directory to `.gitignore`. Typically, you don't want your bundled code version controlled. You should rely on your build tools to handle this (you can add `webpack` to your `package.json`'s `postinstall` if you want to simplify the installation for consumers of your project).

> In hindsight, I realize you probably only added the `dist` directory because I asked to see the bundled code. Sorry! :p But I'll leave this here in case it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Thank you! I finally found out that it is because browser supports most of the es6 features but not webpack "transpiles"(and webpack does not do that without explicit configuration) codes into es5 that my es6 codes run on browser... Can't believe how foolish I am  ;_;

Comment: And its my mistake not excluding the `dist` fold in gitignore ;_;

Comment: Since most es6 features have been supported by most of the modern browsers, is it ok to simply use es6 code without transpiling to es5 if older-brower-compatibility is not considered?

Comment: If the only browsers you're targeting support the features you need, then I'd say you're good to go. Check out https://caniuse.com/#search=es6 for a nice summary of browser support & http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for more detail (just be sure to read the legend up top; the colors are a slightly misleading)